# variable grouping? or filling available slot from pool

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i am creating a execution list for some kind of engine, which executes 10 tasks at a time.
the tasks are two types: standalone and dependent.
dependent ones should be executed in ExecutionOrder, grouped by ExecutionGroup, while standalone ones don't care which group they are assigned or which order they are executed in the assigned group.
so, in one execution group, there are some empty spots.
i.e. when there are 7 dependent tasks in a group, then i can execute 3 standalone in that group.
my data looks like below:

[image: data in two tables]

since each execution group can execute 10 tasks and dependent ones have priority,
and the the objective that i want to achieve looks like below:

[image]

greens are the ExecutionGroup that i need to assign for Standalones, which order doesn't matter
yellows are the overall execution order that i need to assign for both dependent tasks and standalone ones. a brief statistics looks like below:
[image]

below is the data that can create the example that i put above:

```
-- creating temp table, #Dependent
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Dependent') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Dependent;
CREATE TABLE #Dependent (
    ExecutionType       VARCHAR(20)
    , ExecutionTarget   VARCHAR(20)
    , ExecutionGroup    INT
    , ExecutionOrder    INT
);
INSERT INTO #Dependent VALUES ('Dependent', 'bogus1', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO #Dependent VALUES ('Dependent', 'bogus2', 1, 2);
INSERT INTO #Dependent VALUES ('Dependent', 'bogus5', 1, 3);
INSERT INTO #Dependent VALUES ('Dependent', 'bogus8', 1, 4);
INSERT INTO #Dependent VALUES ('Dependent', 'bogus11', 1, 5);
INSERT INTO #Dependent VALUES ('Dependent', 'bogus17', 1, 6);
INSERT INTO #Dependent VALUES ('Dependent', 'bogus20', 1, 7);
INSERT INTO #Dependent VALUES ('Dependent', 'bogus3', 2, 8);
INSERT INTO #Dependent VALUES ('Dependent', 'bogus10', 2, 9);
INSERT INTO #Dependent VALUES ('Dependent', 'bogus12', 2, 10);
INSERT INTO #Dependent VALUES ('Dependent', 'bogus18', 2, 11);
INSERT INTO #Dependent VALUES ('Dependent', 'bogus21', 2, 12);
INSERT INTO #Dependent VALUES ('Dependent', 'bogus4', 3, 13);
INSERT INTO #Dependent VALUES ('Dependent', 'bogus7', 3, 14);
INSERT INTO #Dependent VALUES ('Dependent', 'bogus15', 3, 15);
INSERT INTO #Dependent VALUES ('Dependent', 'bogus16', 3, 16);
INSERT INTO #Dependent VALUES ('Dependent', 'bogus19', 3, 17);
INSERT INTO #Dependent VALUES ('Dependent', 'bogus6', 4, 18);
INSERT INTO #Dependent VALUES ('Dependent', 'bogus13', 4, 19);
INSERT INTO #Dependent VALUES ('Dependent', 'bogus9', 5, 20);

-- creating temp table, #Standalone
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Standalone') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Standalone;
CREATE TABLE #Standalone (
    ExecutionType       VARCHAR(20)
    , ExecutionTarget   VARCHAR(20)
);
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus21');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus22');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus23');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus24');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus25');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus26');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus27');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus28');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus29');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus30');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus31');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus32');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus33');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus34');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus35');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus36');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus37');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus38');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus39');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus40');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus41');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus42');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus43');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus44');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus45');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus46');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus47');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus48');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus49');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus50');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus51');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus52');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus53');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus54');
INSERT INTO #Standalone VALUES ('Standalone', 'bogus55');
```

i've been struggling with dependency calculation for a while and it looks like my brain juice ran out. currently, i came up with a WHILE loop that deletes a certain number of rows from #Standlone until #Standlone becomes empty, and that looks ugly. i couldn't come up with brilliant solution. any feedback will be helpful. thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With large amounts of data, I would not do this as a single CTE, but this should give you point to iterate from:

```
WITH Groupings AS (
    SELECT 10 AS SIZE
)
, SequenceOfNumbers AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) Number FROM Sys.Columns C CROSS JOIN Sys.Columns C1
)
, Counts AS (
    
    SELECT  Size
        ,(
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Dependent) 
                + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Standalone) 
                + (Size -1) /* Force Round Up*/
            ) /  Size GroupCount
        ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Dependent) DependentCount
         ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Standalone) StandAloneCount
    FROM Groupings
)
, TotalGroups AS (
    SELECT TOP (SELECT GroupCount FROM Counts) Number GroupID FROM SequenceOfNumbers
)
, SlotsPerGroup AS (
    SELECT TOP (SELECT Size FROM Counts) Number SlotPosition FROM SequenceOfNumbers
)
, InitialSlots AS (
    SELECT 
        CAST(GroupID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ':' + CAST(SlotPosition -1 AS VARCHAR(10)) SlotID
        , GroupID
        , SlotPosition
    FROM 
        TotalGroups
        CROSS JOIN SlotsPerGroup

)
, Dependents AS(
    SELECT *
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ExecutionGroup) GroupNumber
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ExecutionGroup ORDER BY ExecutionOrder) AS GroupSeq  
    FROM #Dependent 
)
, DependentFilledSlots AS (
    SELECT 
        I.*
        , d.ExecutionType
        , d.ExecutionTarget
        , d.ExecutionGroup
        , d.ExecutionOrder
    FROM InitialSlots I
         LEFT JOIN Dependents D ON Groupid = GroupNumber
            AND SlotPosition = GroupSeq

)
, RemainingSlots AS (
    SELECT 
        SlotID
      , GroupID
      , SlotPosition
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) Position
    FROM DependentFilledSlots WHERE ExecutionType IS NULL
)
, StandAlones AS (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY(SELECT 1)) AS Seq  
    FROM #Standalone
)
, StandAloneSlotes AS (
    SELECT 
        r.SlotID
      , r.GroupID
      , r.SlotPosition
      , s.ExecutionType
      , s.ExecutionTarget

    FROM RemainingSlots r JOIN StandAlones s ON r.Position = s.Seq

)
,  AllSlots AS (
    SELECT GroupID, SlotPosition, ExecutionType, ExecutionTarget, GroupID ExecutionGroup FROM DependentFilledSlots WHERE ExecutionType IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL  SELECT  GroupID, SlotPosition, ExecutionType, ExecutionTarget, GroupID ExecutionGroup FROM  StandAloneSlotes
)

SELECT 
  ExecutionType
  , ExecutionTarget
  , ExecutionGroup 
  , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY GroupID, SlotPosition) AS ExecutionOrder
FROM AllSlots 
ORDER BY GroupID, SlotPosition
```

---

My Results:

| ExecutionType | ExecutionTarget | ExecutionGroup | ExecutionOrder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dependent | bogus1 | 1 | 1 |
| Dependent | bogus2 | 1 | 2 |
| Dependent | bogus5 | 1 | 3 |
| Dependent | bogus8 | 1 | 4 |
| Dependent | bogus11 | 1 | 5 |
| Dependent | bogus17 | 1 | 6 |
| Dependent | bogus20 | 1 | 7 |
| Standalone | bogus21 | 1 | 8 |
| Standalone | bogus22 | 1 | 9 |
| Standalone | bogus23 | 1 | 10 |
| Dependent | bogus3 | 2 | 11 |
| Dependent | bogus10 | 2 | 12 |
| Dependent | bogus12 | 2 | 13 |
| Dependent | bogus18 | 2 | 14 |
| Dependent | bogus21 | 2 | 15 |
| Standalone | bogus24 | 2 | 16 |
| Standalone | bogus25 | 2 | 17 |
| Standalone | bogus26 | 2 | 18 |
| Standalone | bogus27 | 2 | 19 |
| Standalone | bogus28 | 2 | 20 |
| Dependent | bogus4 | 3 | 21 |
| Dependent | bogus7 | 3 | 22 |
| Dependent | bogus15 | 3 | 23 |
| Dependent | bogus16 | 3 | 24 |
| Dependent | bogus19 | 3 | 25 |
| Standalone | bogus29 | 3 | 26 |
| Standalone | bogus30 | 3 | 27 |
| Standalone | bogus31 | 3 | 28 |
| Standalone | bogus32 | 3 | 29 |
| Standalone | bogus33 | 3 | 30 |
| Dependent | bogus6 | 4 | 31 |
| Dependent | bogus13 | 4 | 32 |
| Standalone | bogus34 | 4 | 33 |
| Standalone | bogus35 | 4 | 34 |
| Standalone | bogus36 | 4 | 35 |
| Standalone | bogus37 | 4 | 36 |
| Standalone | bogus38 | 4 | 37 |
| Standalone | bogus39 | 4 | 38 |
| Standalone | bogus40 | 4 | 39 |
| Standalone | bogus41 | 4 | 40 |
| Dependent | bogus9 | 5 | 41 |
| Standalone | bogus42 | 5 | 42 |
| Standalone | bogus43 | 5 | 43 |
| Standalone | bogus44 | 5 | 44 |
| Standalone | bogus45 | 5 | 45 |
| Standalone | bogus46 | 5 | 46 |
| Standalone | bogus47 | 5 | 47 |
| Standalone | bogus48 | 5 | 48 |
| Standalone | bogus49 | 5 | 49 |
| Standalone | bogus50 | 5 | 50 |
| Standalone | bogus51 | 6 | 51 |
| Standalone | bogus52 | 6 | 52 |
| Standalone | bogus53 | 6 | 53 |
| Standalone | bogus54 | 6 | 54 |
| Standalone | bogus55 | 6 | 55 |